# How to add the colon(:) inbetween numbers in oracle sql table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Actual output:

123456

Expected output:

12:34:56

Comment: It's almost always a better idea to leave formatting or presentation concerns to whatever program/system is consuming data from the database rather than trying to perform them down in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Or, try regular expression, such as

```
SQL> select rtrim(regexp_replace('123456', '(\d{2})', '\1:'), ':') result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
--------
12:34:56

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:
You can use `SUBSTR()` to slice the number and `||` to concate those togather.

```
select SUBSTR(nbr,1,2)||':'||SUBSTR(nbr,3,2)||':'||SUBSTR(nbr,5,2) result from
(select 123456 nbr from dual)
```

Output:

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 12:34:56 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OrWB09G)

Answer (score 0):

You have shown the number 123456 and want it formatted as 12:34:56. So you want to get from a number to a string. As '12:34:56' is not a representation of the number 123456 (like '123456' or '123,456' or '123456.0' would be), you need two steps:

1. Convert the number 123456 to a string '123456'.
2. Use string manipulation functions to convert the string '123456' to '12:34:56'.

I don't know what numbers you are dealing with. Can it have eight digits and you want it separated into groups of two? Can it have seven digits? If so, how to format them?

In below example I assume one to six digits, where we'll create leading zeros. E.g. 0 becomes '00:00:00'.

```
select regexp_replace(to_char(num, 'fm000000'), '^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)$', '\1:\2:\3')
from mytable;
```

I am using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here, because I prefer regular expressions for such tasks for their conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a time then convert the number to a `DATE` and then format it as a string:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(123456, 'HH24MISS'), 'HH24:MI:SS') AS time
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| TIME |
| --- |
| 12:34:56 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vKS6lyuj)